# sql question about select - trivial?

Tags: sql, sql-server

seems trivial, but can't find solution -

i need to write query which gets me persons based on values of attributes
(e.g. get me persons which have attr '1' AND '2' AND '3')

**clarification: querying could be done on more than three value of attributes
- it will be user selected - from 0 to n values, but i don't expect more than 7 values...   **

```
-- tsql script --------------
create table ##temp (person char(1), attr char(1)  );

-- can be 1..n persons and 1..n attributes
insert into ##temp VALUES 
('A','1'),
('A','2'),
('B','1'),
('C','2');

-- sample: get all persons which have attribute 1 AND 2
-- sample: result should be 'A' only

drop table ##temp
-- tsql script -----------------
```

thanks for helping,
hh

Answer (score 5):

You could use a `GROUP BY`with a `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT)`clause.

#### SQL Statement

```
SELECT  person
FROM    ##temp
WHERE   attr IN ('1', '2')
GROUP BY 
        person
HAVING  COUNT(DISTINCT attr) = 2
```

Following statement will always outperform the `COUNT(DISTINCT)` but will yield incorrect results if duplicates are present. *please note that the outperformance might not be measurable*.

```
SELECT  person
FROM    ##temp
WHERE   attr IN ('1', '2')
GROUP BY 
        person
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

Comment: And if there *are* duplicates, you could use a `GROUP BY` with a `HAVING` clause. :) But with a slightly different condition: `COUNT(DISTINCT attr) = 2`.

Comment: @Andriy M - thanks for teaching me something new. I have altered my answer to include your comment.

Comment: My opinion is that COUNT(DISTINCT) generates more overhead than COUNT() and should avoided if possible.

Comment: @niktrs - true but it would work in all cases whereas my original answer wouldn't. It is up to the OP to decide between robustness and speed (if measurable).

Comment: Between robustness and speed I think everyone prefers... robustness! Maybe would be nice to add both options in your answer - depending if duplicates exists.

Answer (score 1):

You can join the table to itself:

```
select t1.person
from ##temp t1
inner join ##temp t2 on t2.person = t1.person and t2.attr = '2'
where t1.attr = '1'
```

As this need another join for each added attribute, it's not very flexible. On the other hand, if you add `distinct` it will also handle duplicate attributes.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer - but as you already noticed, it would require multiple joins - thank you anyway...

Answer (score 1):

normal you have 1 table for person where every person is listed singletime, 
and a second table with the atributes

```
select person from (
  select person, count(person) as cnt from ##temp where attr in (1,2,3) group by person
) where cnt = 3
```

this should do the work

but in your testing table was only attr 1 and 2 ... so this won't show any results

```
select person from (
  select person, count(person) as cnt from ##temp where attr in (1,2) group by person
) where cnt = 2
```

will show you A

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you want this to be dynamic, you would either have to build your query using **dynamic sql** like

```
SELECT person FROM ###temp WHERE attr = '1' AND attr = '2'
```

where the **WHERE** part is build up using the data you provide that you would like to search for. This is however not a good idea due to the limitations it brings in form of query optimizations. So a better way would be to provide the **attrs** as a comma separated string and splitting it using a split function. The result of that could then be inserted into another temporary table and used in the main query with the ability to keep most of the optimizations the query analyzer could do for you.

An example of a split function could be

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.Split(@String varchar(8000), 
                          @Delimiter char(1))       
returns @temptable TABLE (items varchar(8000))       
as       
begin       
    declare @idx int       
    declare @slice varchar(8000)       

    select @idx = 1       
        if len(@String)<1 or @String is null  return       

    while @idx!= 0       
    begin       
        set @idx = charindex(@Delimiter,@String)       
        if @idx!=0       
            set @slice = left(@String,@idx - 1)       
        else       
            set @slice = @String       

        if(len(@slice)>0)  
            insert into @temptable(Items) values(@slice)       

        set @String = right(@String,len(@String) - @idx)       
        if len(@String) = 0 break       
    end   
return       
end
```

You could then do a query something like

```
SELECT person 
FROM ###temp
WHERE attr IN(SELECT CONVERT(int, items) FROM dbo.Split(@attrs, ','))
GROUP BY person 
HAVING ( COUNT(person) = @numattrs )
```

The **@numattrs** value should be the number of attributes you use in your search. Either supplied to you procedure or fetched using something like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.Split(@attrs, ',')
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer - you assumed correct that i'll build it dynamic - that group by and having somehow didn't occur to me :) - btw. COUNT is better with DISTINCT (thanks to Andriy M)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think doing this is going to help:

```
SELECT person FROM ###temp WHERE attr = '1' AND attr = '2'
```

no attr value is ever going to be 1 and 2 simultaneously!!

if you make your attr field bigint, and use binary values 1,2,4,8,16 etc, then

```
select person from table group by person having sum (attr) = 3
```

will find you where person has an entry for 1 and an entry for 2 (exactly).
Similarly

`having sum(attr) | 11`   means it includes 1,2, and 8 and maybe others. Look up bitwise functions OR, AND NOT etc
NOTE this is limited by bigint, ie you can have about 63 different attr values.

Comment: Sorry I meant to edit this to "having sum(attr) | 11 > 0 ", but I have a really poor browser version here, and it won't let me, for some reason.

Comment: thank you for your time and answer - but i can't choose values for attribute - they are random int numbers (1,2,3,...n)